# mysql merging lines function

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a table in mysql where thousands of phone calls are saved. Some telephone operators send telephone calls in multiple records. Phone calls are shuffled and must first be sorted by caller, called and date.

Here is an example

```
    Id|Caller|Called|Date|Length|CallerImei|CallerImsi|CalledImei|CalledImsi|CallerCGIStart|CallerCGIEnd|CalledCGIStart|CalledCGIEND
   "9"|"+39123"|"+39321"|"2018-08-03 03:10:18"|"351"|"8629"|"222"|""|""|"0117"|""|""|""
  "16"|"+39222"|"+39111"|"2018-08-03 03:17:04"|"106"|"8629"|"222"|""|""|"4590"|""|""|""
  "18"|"+39222"|"+39111"|"2018-08-03 03:17:04"|"106"|"" |""|"8629"|"222"|""|""|"4590"|""
   "3"|"+39333"|"+39355"|"2018-08-03 03:06:23"|"146"|"8630"|"222"|""|""|"0117"|""|""|""
```

In the row with ids 16 and 18, the call is divided into two records. In line 16 there is some information, in row 18 there are others. We can recognize the call because it has the same date, same duration and the same caller and called. Also some phone calls may have more than two lines or the duration may be slightly lower, but if the previous phone call lasted longer than the one that follows it ... it is definitely the same phone call.

I would like to do a merge this way.

```
Id |Caller|Called|Date|Length|CallerImei|CallerImsi|CalledImei|CalledImsi|CallerCGIStart|CallerCGIEnd|CalledCGIStart|CalledCGIEND|ListIDMerged
"1"|"+39123"|"+39321"|"2018-08-03 03:10:18"|"351"|"8629"|"222"|""|""|"0117"|""|""|""|"9"
"2"|"+39222"|"+39111"|"2018-08-03 03:17:04"|"106"|"8629"|"222"|"8629"|"222"|"4590"|""|"4590"|""|"16,18"
"3"|"+39333"|"+39355"|"2018-08-03 03:06:23"|"146"|"8630"|"222"|""|""|"0117"|""|""|""|"3"
```

Then create a table with the result of the merge and a column that takes into account the merged rows for a possible control

Thanks for all

Comment: first build your select to get the data in a row. Then combine it with a insert where instead of specific values you have your select

Comment: do you say before creating a table where phone calls are ordered?

Comment: no, after. The table is created once and is empty. Then you do select and insert from the source

Comment: the table is not empty and phone calls can arrive with days and days of delay. As soon as they arrive they are inserted into the table

Comment: your sample is not clear  ...

Comment: How can I make it clearer than that? I have a table with thousands of phone calls that I want to "clean" by merging phone calls divided into several records